# "This is hitting me" (AmE)

Tags: verbs, usage, american-english

I'm watching a show where a girl receives a text from a guy she really likes. When she tells it to her friend, she says: "Wow, this is hitting me", and I don't know how to interpret "hit" in this context. Since she is very excited, my best guess is that it means something along the lines of "This is overwhelming" or "This is amazing", but I'm not really sure. Can you help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: What did the text say/

Comment: Hello! :) I can't recall the exact dialogue, but it was something like:
- Oh my gosh! Jack texted me. I'm so excited.
- Wow! And what did he say?
- He wanna go out. This is hitting me. It's been a long time since I last dated someone.